# Music Fans election?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I was just curious if there were any moderator elections planned in the near future for this site?  A lot of Meta questions on other sites rely heavily on answers from mods, and some of the editing privilidges here can only be done by the owner(s) because no one else has enough rep.  While it may be trivial, certain things like approving Wiki edits are taking several days, whereas if the owner(s) had some help it could be knocked out quickly.

So, are there any elections planned to get the owner(s) some help?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/

Comment: The pro tem moderator selection process is in progress.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For brand new sites, the Community Moderators will appoint a set of Moderators Pro Tem, who will shepherd the site through the beta process. When it is ready to graduate, there will be a mature and established community, which will make regular moderator elections possible and meaningful.

Comment: Is the Mooderators Pro Tem permanent during the beta process? Whether the beta process lasts 1 year or 5 years?

Comment: The appointed moderators pro tem are more-or-less permanent in that they continue to server as long as they are willing, able, and don't screw up too badly. If the community managers find that the number of mods pro tem is inadequate, they will appoint replacements.

Answer (score 4):

How about starting a nomination thread, since we've already had a few declined and non-responses?

We need folks to step up and volunteer to administer the moderation of this site.

---

Edit: Done.

[**Who would like to help moderate this site?**](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181/who-would-you-like-to-help-moderate-this-site)