# Who would you like to help moderate this site?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until this site reaches a critical mass to hold an election, we will be appointing some provisional Moderators to fill that role.

We need your help. Please nominate some folks you might like to see become the provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide some valuable support to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)**.

### The Nomination Process:

- Nominate a user by adding an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity. I added a short template (below) to help you with that process.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- Nominations can include links to other activities: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **The nominee should indicate their acceptance** by editing the answer (not commenting) to say they accept. Optionally, nominees are encouraged to write a bit about themselves following the nomination. You can use the `---` markup to separate the nominee's commentary from the original nomination. See the example below.

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are seeking out members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation.
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Here is an example nomination entry. You can copy-and-paste from the format below:

> `<h2>[username](<main profile link>) </h2>`
>
> `<h2>[Meta Profile](<meta profile link>) </h2>`
>
> `Notes:`
>
> `<why you feel nominee would be a useful addition to the pro tem choices>`
>
> `---`
>
> <sup><sup>(this section is edited in by the nominee)</sup></sup>
>
> `I accept/decline this nomination`
>
> `I am name/age/location/fun fact/all optional. I live in location, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are`…
>
> `etc.`

Answer (score 7):

### [Donald.McLean](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/users/27/donald-mclean)

[Meta](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/users/27/donald-mclean)

Seems a reasonable chap, a consensus builder, and someone who has good SE experience. His current 'rep' on the main site is a little misleading : he has been around the site more often than most, and in any case being a strong mod requires different skills to just being a user.

also, rumour has it that he might not decline...

---

I accept the nomination. I am a huge lover of music and believe in the potential of this site.

Answer (score 6):

Main Site: [Dom](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/users/7/dom)

Meta: [Dom](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/users/7/dom)

Notes:

One of the more underrated aspect of community involvement is chat, and Dom has certainly been active there. And he has been active both on the site and meta.

---

I accept this nomination.

I live in Philadelphia and will check the site periodically between 8:00 AM and 9:00 PM. I've been an active musician and a music fan for a good portion of my life and currently getting a Minor in Music Composition & Theory and getting a bachelors in Electrical/Computer Engineering. I'm typically not too pick when it comes to listening to music, but I'll typically gravitate to alternative rock and the like.

Comment: Dom seems like a good option. My only worry is that he is deep in the "trigger happy" side of things in the Music Theory SE (as a user), and I don't want to see this site become a close fest. Other than that, he is very active pretty much everywhere and very knowledgable about music, but I'm not sure if he has the critical thinking qualities a mod should have. You can check his close vote history in the Music Theory SE and judge by yourself (if you have enough rep). In my opinion, he'd make a great mod if he wasn't so trigger happy.

Comment: I finally stopped by chat and see Dom has been active there.  However, chat is somewhat dead, and there hasn't been anything discussed of importance at least in the past 2 weeks (I didn't look further back than that).

Comment: @JCPedroza You and anyone else can see all my reviews on [Music SE](http://music.stackexchange.com/users/7222/dom?tab=activity) and on [Music Fan SE](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/users/7/dom?tab=activity&sort=reviews&page=1). I'm not perfect and I don't claim, but I do take all reviews on this and other SE seriously and don't just click "close","leave open", or  anything else lightly. I do have my own opinions on topics that may differ from others and will always have them, but this is a community and how the community feels about questions I take into account very seriously reviewing.

Answer (score 3):

### [JCPedroza](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/users/70/jcpedroza)

[Meta](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/users/70/jcpedroza)

There will inevitably be discussion over what the we want the site to be, and I think JC has an ability to move conversations past the 'log jam of opinions' stage. Also is a knowledgeable contributor to the site and one of the most active Meta users.

---

I appreciate the nomination, but unfortunately I have to decline it. I'm having busy days (thankfully), not enough free time to meaningfully participate in the mod team.

Answer (score 2):

### [Shevliaskovic](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/users/24/shevliaskovic)

### [Meta Profile](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/users/24/shevliaskovic)

I think he's a good candidate because:

- He's been active in both the main site and the meta since day one
  making great contributions to both.
- On this SE and other SEs he consistently goes through all the review queues.
- He's shown on other sites like Music: Practice and Theory that is very active and very committed to the SE model and understands it well.

---

Answer (score 2):

### topo morto

[Meta profile](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16/topo-morto)

Very active on the site. Not so set in the SO way of SE. I believe the nature of the subject calls for the site to be a bit more freewheeling than some other places in the network, hence I think he will be a good candidate.

---

Sorry but I'll **decline** - I've been able to visit the site a lot so far, but my availability can vary quite a bit so I couldn't promise to be around as much as a mod probably should.

Comment: Thanks but I'll decline for now - BTW if you (Meaningful Username) were interested in standing you'd have my vote for much the same reasons you said, plus I think you are a bit better at the diplomacy than I am!

Comment: @topomorto: I think you are in the minority when it comes to the diplomacy :). I think I'm too much at odds with how a large part of the community feels an SE should work to do a good job, plus I haven't been sufficiently active here to warrant a moderator position.

Comment: ...Though you are one of the few who have bothered to talk about some of the issues in chat. Very few people have been particularly active on the main site... recently there's not been much going on, and nearer the beginning the split over the direction of the site was a bit of a distraction. Would be interested to talk about the ways in which the stats could be boosted a bit but both the meta and the chat are rather quiet too...

Answer (score 1):

Main Site: [Johnny Bones](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/users/53/johnny-bones)

Meta: [Johnny Bones](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/users/53/johnny-bones)

Notes:

I would like to throw my hat into the ring on this.  I've been around since the opening bell, have the 2nd most rep here, and have visited every day since I joined.  I feel I'm fairly knowledgeable on music-related topics and would love to be among the first moderators to help shape the site.  Additionally, it was my [Meta post](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177/music-fans-election) which got this election started.  :o)

---

I accept this nomination

I am an avid music collector and used to spend most of my paycheck in Greenwich Village in NYC buying records, imports, bootlegs, magazines and posters back when I didn't really have any financial responsibilities.  :o)  I live in Connecticut in the USA, so I am generally active on this site from 8AM EST to 6PM EST. Some other things you may want to know about me are that I am very active on the Music & TV site, and I make my money writing C#/VBA code.  I have close to 500 DVDs and probably 3,000 LPs in my collection.  I play guitar, although I'm not great at it I still enjoy bashing out a tune or two now and then.

Answer (score 1):

### [unor](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/users/47/unor)

[Meta account](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47/unor)

- Has a very high reputation on this website.
- Has never made a post with negative ratings.
- Frequents on many other SE sites.
- Is very active on Music Fans.

---

I decline this nomination.

Comment: Thanks for the nomination, DJ Aftershock, but I decline :) (I was nominated before and declined, but the post seems to have been deleted.)

Comment: @unor The post say "deleted by owner." No matter. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: @unor yes, I deleted the post after you declined - but I now realise that may not have been sensible! Congratulations on being the first person to be nominated twice :)