# Should we elect a fourth mod who would be closer and more available?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I have noticing a drop in mods activity, recently. I'm aware that everyone is allowed to "disconnect" and has IRL lives, but wouldn't it help them to have a fourth member in the mod team, to manage day to day tasks?

I suggest we elect a fourth mod that would be more available, active and closer?

Comment: AFAIK, moderator election is done as required. Also, some moderation done by mods is not really visible to regular users. Could you provide more info/reasons why it's needed (e.g. pending flags/votes too long to be handled, etc.)? Are community moderation not enough to handle the current situation?

Comment: @AndrewT., that's correct. We are not enough regular active users so close votes get too much time to conclude and sometimes get outdated. Flags take also some time to get dealt with. If current mods are overwhelmed, it would be nice to have a 4th one to helm them.

Comment: It seems to me there's deeper issues with the site regarding scope, quality, and general community engagement that ought to be tackled before worrying about understaffed moderators. Would anyone even *nominate* for an election?

Answer (score 2):

There is another issue that needs to be solved before we talk about bringing another mod in and that is the community needs to define what it wants this site to be and how it wants to handle moderation on topics like close/open policy on vague questions and what constitutes an answer for an identification.

Currently, there's not a lot to be moderated on the site and the only thing that makes it difficult is it's not obvious what the community as a whole wants. This makes it very difficult to moderate to content we have. I personally tend not to close or delete questions and answers any more as it has caused several problems in the past.

If I were just a regular member, there's a lot of questions I would flag for close with problems in. As a mod I really can't due to flags being binding. I think in general we would benefit from closing and flagging borderline content sooner to try and keep our quality high, but we also have the community in general active enough in moderation to also handle the reopening of questions when the content has been adjusted.

Comment: Hi Dom... to me the question on how to handle moderation about vague questions has already been discussed and seems pretty clear. The tour, the identify-xxx tags, and meta topics agreed that ID questions need to have a decent amount of details and answer need to be complete, with links, matching details etc...

Comment: @Bebs but nobody is following up on the actions on those.   Questions with little detail are still numerous on the site. There's also the question of how to deal with low quality answers from those questions. A lot of the answers to those types of questions are flagged by the system as low quality so we have a much higher auto flag count than other sites.

Comment: *we have a much higher auto flag count than other sites*, is it a problem? We can't control what people write, but we can control what we do about bas post. That was my whole point about electing a fourth mod, to have a quicker response on this bad posts. Look [here](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391/why-has-this-correct-answer-answer-been-deleted-ii).

Comment: @Bebs again, that linked meta post shows this problem. The community has several members that can do this and when mods have stepped in it has cause problems in the past. We can have more aggressive moderation of the site, but we need the community as a whole to meet that challenge and aid in both finding issues and helping follow up.  Honestly,  it's not the fact that we have a lot of auto flags it's the fact that handling the auto flags has caused friction several times on the site hence we need a better idea of what the community wants. I'm willing to put the time in, but I need a direction

Answer (score 0):

[Dom's answer](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/a/178/53) to a question oh so many years ago really defines why there is no fourth mod.

In 4 years, we haven't graduated out of Beta.  That's not good.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to bring back this topic because I've been concerned these days.

I'm worried today that no mod is pingable on the chat. I understand that being a mod seems to be very gratifying so I am certainly not asking them to quit.

Some of their decisions these last days have been weird I think.

Please mods, reconsider this. A fourth mod will not destroy your power and you will still have your rewarding title. It will help the community for those who are actually interested.

Comment: I doubt anyone is all that "gratified" by being a mod, it's a tedious and largely thankless job that people do largely out of a sense of responsibility.  But I'd be all in favor of adding another mod.  Are you volunteering?  I think you, me and Brahadeesh are the only active members here who AREN'T mods, and *I'm* not volunteering :D

Comment: @ChrisSunami, I know it's not that gratifying when you actually do the job. But it seems that from some people it's an additional line on their resumé or a way to brag with their friends, or something else... anyway, I was considering *you* as volunteer.

Comment: LOL, nice try :D

Comment: @Brahadeesh - I think you'd make a great mod :) But to be honest, the problem we have isn't not enough mods, it's not enough questions...